# Equality of addition of four real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, logic

I have the below question from Tao Analysis 1 book [exercise A.7.1].
Suppose you have four real numbers $a, b, c, d$ and you know that $a = b$ and $c = d$. Use the above four axioms to deduce that $a + d = b + c$.

The book states that to prove equality, we have to satisfy four axioms.
**1. (Reflexive axiom). Given any object x, we have x = x.

2. (Symmetry axiom). Given any two objects x and y of the same
type, if x = y, then y = x.

3. (Transitive axiom). Given any three objects x, y, z of the same
type, if x = y and y = z, then x = z.

4. (Substitution axiom). Given any two objects x and y of the same
type, if x = y, then f(x) = f(y) for all functions or operations f.**

I prove Reflexive axiom as
$$ a = a \implies a+d = a+d$$
Symmetry axiom as
$$ \text{if } a+d = b+c \text{ then } b+d=b+c  \quad(a = b) $$
$$b+d = a+c \quad(a = b \implies b=a) $$
$$b+c =a+c \quad (c=d \implies d = c)$$
$$ b+c = a+d \quad (c=d)$$
Transitive axiom as
If $a+d = b+c$ and $b+c = e+f$ then $a+d = e+f$
Substitution axiom as
If $a+d = b+c $ and let $f$ be a function then function gives a unique value to same input , thus $f(a+d) = f(b+c)$. Since f was an arbitrary function ,therefore, $a+d = b+c \implies f(a+d) = f(b+c) $ for all functions.

Is the above proof justified for the question asked?

Comment: You aren't supposed to prove the axioms.  The axioms are given to be true.. And they are *always* true.  You are supposed to *use* the axioms to prove $a+d=b+c$. Note that's all you are supposed to do.

Comment: Hint:  Let $f(x) = x + d$ to prove $a=b \implies a+d = b+ d$. And let $g(x) = b+ x$ to prove $c=d$ to imply $b+c = b+ d$.

Comment: @fleablood, you mean, Let $f(x) =x+d$. By Substitution axiom $f(a) =f(b) \implies a+d =b+ d$. Let $g(x) =b+x$. By Substitution axiom $g(d) =g(c) \implies b+d =b+ c$.  
Since $a+d = b+d $ and $b+d = b+c$. By Transitive axiom $a+d = b+c$

Comment: Yes... that's the key step.  Although you will also need a transitive axiom.  $f(a) = a+d$ by defiinition; $f(b) = b+ d$ by def; a=b so $f(a) =f(b)$ by substitution; $a+d =f(a)$ by symetry; so $a+d=f(a)$ and $f(a)=f(b)$ imply $a+d=f(b)$ by transitivity; and $a+d=f(b)$ and $f(b) = b+ d$ imply $a+d =b+d$ but transitivity again.  Now you are about 1/4 of the way there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @fleablood comment the answer to the question is
Let f(x)=x+d. By substitution axiom $$f(a)=f(b)⟹a+d=b+d$$
Let g(x)=b+x. By substitution axiom $$g(d)=g(c)⟹b+d=b+c$$
Since $a+d=b+d$ and $b+d=b+c$. By transitive axiom $a+d=b+c$

Comment: @fleablood can you please check the answer and vote up